# Python Modules Segfault

Tags: python, segmentation-fault

when I try and run python->help()->modules I get this:

```
% python
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Apr 13 2012, 11:08:33) [C] on sunos5

>>> help()

help> modules

Please wait a moment while I gather a list of all available modules...
file ghash.c: line 875: assertion `hash_table->ref_count > 0' failedfile ghash.c: line 875: assertion `hash_table->ref_count > 0' failed
Segmentation Fault
```

and just like that, down it goes.  My question is why?  and How can I fix it?

I can access the modules fine in code, just can't bring up the list from the help menu.  The other tags from help work fine too.  It is just this one that breaks

Comment: Interesting.  I can't reproduce this.

Comment: @mgilson: It's *a* extension module, but probably not one in the stdlib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `python -vv` and repeat your steps. See what module fails to import.

Or install [`faulthandler`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/faulthandler). Enable it and repeat your steps.

Comment: I dunno, there were no failed imports. Everything went through fine. Can't install faulthadler, not admin at work

Comment: @Squid1361: you don't need to be admin. Install in `~/.local` (--user option) or use virtualenv. What are the last lines before the segfault with `python -vv`?

Comment: I will give a run at installing that then.